# ON the Kronecker product form of the laplacian matrix

Tags: finite-element, finite-difference, poisson, elliptic-pde, laplacian

It's well known that if we use 2nd order, centered, finite differences for the Laplace operator, we have that the matrix can be written as $$K=I \otimes A + A \otimes I $$ where $I$ is the identity matrix and $A$ is the classical 1D matrix with stencil $\frac{1}{h^2}[1 ,-2, 1]$

My question is: in case I want to employ *finite elements*, the corresponding matrix stems from $(\nabla v_i, \nabla v_j)_{\Omega}$. **Does it still have the same structure as before?**

For instance, if I use DG basis functions, do I end up with a Kronecker sum structure as before?

Comment: That at the very least depends on what kind of mesh you have. If you only want to consider structured quadrilateral meshes, you might want to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is too general.

In 1D the discrete linear FE operator often recovers the linear centered FD one, however this is not always the case.
For DG you additionally have consider the contribution of the surface integral, which is different for various methods, e.g., SIP or LDG or BR2.

The Kronecker product structure you mentioned makes only sense for the multivariate case.
For example if you want to calculate a 2D differential operator $\mathbf{D}_2$ on tensor-product elements you generally proceed:

$\xi$-direction (or $x$):

$\mathbf{D}_2^{\xi} = \mathbf{D}_1 \otimes \mathbf{I}_1$

$\eta$-direction (or $y$):

$\mathbf{D}_2^{\eta} = \mathbf{I}_1 \otimes \mathbf{D}_1$

For a 2D Laplacian operator this would be:

$ \mathbf{\mathcal{L}}_2 := \mathbf{D}_2^{\xi}\mathbf{D}_2^{\xi} + \mathbf{D}_2^{\eta} \mathbf{D}_2^{\eta} \\
\hspace{0.5cm} = (\mathbf{D}_1\otimes\mathbf{I}_1) (\mathbf{D_1}\otimes\mathbf{I_1}) + (\mathbf{I_1}\otimes\mathbf{D_1}) (\mathbf{I}_1 \otimes\mathbf{D}_1)\\
\hspace{0.5cm} = (\mathbf{D}_1\mathbf{D}_1)\otimes (\mathbf{I_1}\mathbf{I_1}) + (\mathbf{I_1}\mathbf{I_1}) \otimes (\mathbf{D}_1 \mathbf{D}_1)$

using the relation

$(\mathbf{A} \otimes \mathbf{B})(\mathbf{C} \otimes \mathbf{D}) = (\mathbf{AC}) \otimes (\mathbf{BD}).$

Note that this simple formula for the Laplacian is only valid on **Cartesian coordinates** and concerns only the volume part of FE or DG formulations.

For arbitrary elements and unstructured meshes this looks different.

Comment: Sure, I was talking about the multivariate case. I am curious about your last sentence: with "arbitrary elements" you mean something like Thomas Raviart, for instance?  @ConvexHull

Comment: @bobinthebox Not necessarily. If you discretisize your domain for example with bilinear quad elements you additionally have to consider spatial metric terms, both in the volume- and also in the surface integral. Your question is ask quite general. Maybe you can give us a more concrete example.

Comment: I see what you mean: surface contributions to the matrix (as in SIP) are going to destroy the kronecker structure. To give a more concrete example: let's say I want to solve the poisson problem with classical Lagrangian finite elements of order higher than 1 (say 3) on a rectangle. Do I end up again with that Kronecker form for the grad/grad term? @ConvexHull

Comment: I do not think that the Kronecker nomenclature won't be applicable. I only state that your formula above will look different. I am quite sure, that you can write all discrete operators using Kronecker nomenclature.

Comment: The form should not change with higher polynomial orders.

Comment: Okay, so in practice the Kronecker form will not appear if one has unstructured meshes *or* surface contributions, right? Just to make two simple examples @ConvexHull

Comment: Yes the simplicity is lost if you use unstructured meshes. Considering a quad mesh you may end up with more or less than 8 neighbor elements (including diagonal elements).

Comment: I have edited some typos in my (careless) answer.